# convert HQL query to criteria api

Tags: nhibernate, api, hql, criteria

I'm wondering if is possible to convert this HQL query into a criteria api query.

```
select s1 
from Student
where 
     (
        select max(s2.Score)
        from Student
        where s1.Id = s2.Id
     )
      = 10
```

(selects the students that have their max score value equal to 10)

I don't know if I could use a detached criteria because of the 's1.Id = s2.Is' condition

Thanx for anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

her goes

```
var subquery = Session.CreateCriteria<Student>()
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Id", "s1.Id"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("Score"));

var results = Session.CreateCriteria<Student>("s1")
    .Add(Subqueries.Eq(10, subquery))
    .List<Patient>();
```

but i'm not sure if the original query is correct because the subquery should always return 1 row if Id is the primary key